# How to record Skype audio on Android?

Tags: applications, skype, call-recording

I saw some similar questions here, but they discuss recording Skype video, -- which I don't need. Also, the solutions only suggest ways to record 1 side of the conversation. I tried to use Real call recorder and All call recorder apps but they only recorded 1 side of the conversation -- my side.

Is there a way to record Skype audio where it records **both sides of the conversation**? I have a rooted Android 4.2.1

Comment: @learneX any luck with this?

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife I ended up using my computer with Linux OS to record the Skype audio both ways. It required some tinkering, but with the help of some folks here at Stackexchange, I was able to do it. I can link that post here if you need it.  No luck with recording on Android though.

Comment: @learneX Wow, that sounds like a pain in the ass. Sorry,you had to go through that. I would love the link to that. I wonder if there is some tasker functionality that can be done. Did you ever look into that? Meaning have every time you used the skype app, it would run the internal mic?

Comment: Here's the link to how I did it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147241/how-to-record-skype-calls-audio-on-debian-6   As you can see, it is complicated but it did end up working for me perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. It seems that the issue with android is the two microphone issue. Apparently you can only use one mic at a time. Thanks again!